# Do something while Button is pressed

Tags: c++-cli

Heay everyone,
I want to implement a button, which is doing something while it is pressed.

The idea is to start a thread when the button is clicked (MouseDown) and to stop it when the button is released (MouseUp).
The eventhandler:

```
this->button18->MouseUp += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Demo::button18_MouseUp);
this->button18->MouseDown += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Demo::button18_MouseDown);
```

The events:

```
private: System::Void button18_MouseUp(System::Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
    stop = true;
    button18_Thread->Join();

}//end of button18_MouseUp

private: System::Void button18_MouseDown(System::Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e)
{
    stop = false;
    button18_Thread = gcnew Thread(my_move_Thread);
    button18_Thread->Start();
}//end of button18_MouseDown
```

The thread decleration and function:

```
ThreadStart^ my_move_Thread = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Demo::move);
Thread^ button18_Thread;

void move()
{
    while (!stop)
    {
        label17->Text = Convert::ToString(--act_vel);
    }//end of while

}//end of move
```

Can anyone tell me why the program ends in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the boolean stop and Thread->Join(), I just use Thread->Abort() now and it works.
Still I would love to know why the Thread->Join() ends in a loop.